# Groupby replace values with there max value pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this DataFrame

```
lst = [['AAA',15],['BBB',16],['BBB',22],['AAA',20],['CCC',11],['AAA',10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['name','val'])
```

which looks like this

```
  name  val
0  AAA   15
1  BBB   16
2  BBB   22
3  AAA   20
4  CCC   11
5  AAA   10
```

I want this

```
  name  val
0  AAA   20
1  BBB   22
2  BBB   22
3  AAA   20
4  CCC   11
5  AAA   20
```

replaced all `val` with the maximum of there `name` group

I did this so far

```
dd = df.groupby('name')['val'].max().to_dict()
```

which will give me the dictionary of all the max `val` now i have to replace them using this dictionary.

If i do this after this will replace all the `name` with `val` but i want to replace all the `val` according to there `name`

```
df.replace({"name": dd})
```

Comment: Use `df["val"] = df.groupby("name")["val"].transform("max")`.

Comment: @Henry Yik more gentle way, this should be the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want/need to go through a dictionary, you could [DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a function to facilitate the changes:

```
import pandas as pd
```

> ```
> lst = [['AAA',15],['BBB',16],['BBB',22],['AAA',20],['CCC',11],['AAA',10]]
> df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['name','val'])    
> dd = df.groupby('name')['val'].max().to_dict()
> ```

```
df["val"] = df["name"].apply(lambda d: dd[d])

print (df)
```

or as pointed out by [Ch3steR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12416453/ch3ster) in the comment

```
df["val"] = df["name"].map(dd)
```

looks even smarter. See [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

Output:

```
  name  val
0  AAA   20
1  BBB   22
2  BBB   22
3  AAA   20
4  CCC   11
5  AAA   20
```

Comment: Instead of using `.apply` this looks like perfect use case of `pd.Series.map`...`df["name"].apply(lambda d: dd[d])` can be written as `df['name'].map(dd)`

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = [['AAA',15],['BBB',16],['BBB',22],['AAA',20],['CCC',11],['AAA',10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns = ['name','val'])

max = df.groupby('name').max()
df=df.merge(max,on='name')
del df['val_x']

print(df)
  name  val_y
0  AAA     20
1  AAA     20
2  AAA     20
3  BBB     22
4  BBB     22
5  CCC     11
```